# Multithreading C#. How to know when all threads have finished with my object

Tags: multithreading, queue, message, multiplayer

I'm working on a server for a multiplayer game.
Every client contains a concurrent queue and a thread that runs trough that queue and sends the messages that are stored

Whenever I want to send a message to some clients I just run trough the collection of clients to find the correct ones and I add that message to the queue.

In order to reduce the garbage collector pressure, I implemented a recycling system for the messages, so whenever you call message.Recycle() it's sent to a pool.

The problem is that I don't know if that message has been processed by all the clients or not. And it's not safe to send the message to the pool while it hasn't been processed.

How can I know if that message has been processed by all the clients and it's safe to be recycled?

Comment: You need some abstract container `MessageCopies` per message. Now when each thread finished processing message it marks it as "processed". You can then trigger some action on `MessageCopies` once all associated messages are processed. This can be heavily simplified with C#'s `Task` class and async `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Micro-optimizing gen #0 of the heap is not very useful.  But if you want to anyway then you will have to keep track of these message objects so you can re-use them.  Consider a `ConcurrentBag<Message>` of used messages, put them in the bag after processing a message.

Comment: @HansPassant I already have a recycling system, the problem is that I don't know **when** I should add the message to the bag as I don't have a way to tell when all the threads of all the clients have finished serializing it. 
Also, the server must be able to run on a raspberry pi so the resources are quite limited that's why I'm micro-optimizing the GC

Comment: You'll have to make the "clients" smarter about it, they always know.  Short-lived allocations in gen #0 do not have anything to do with "resources".

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestions. Is there any way to know with the default VS diagnostic tool if the messages are in gen #0?

Comment: They are always in gen #0, that is where any small object starts.